# Install react-bootstrap once or for every project?

Tags: reactjs, installation, react-bootstrap

I'm new to react. A tutorial had me install react-bootstrap.

Is that something that needs to be installed just once per environment? Or do we install it on every project?

Comment: You'll have it install it for each project.

Comment: You replied as comment instead of an Answer, so I couldn't mark it as accepted. But I AM grateful for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-bootstrap is a dependency for a project so you have to install it on every project